# Handbrake produces pixelated output

Tags: handbrake

Until recently Handbrake was working just fine. I think with the update to 0.10.0, something in my setup was broken and I can no longer properly rip DVDs. I'm on Windows 8.1 (64 bit), and the output of my DVD rips is now very pixelated and unusable.

I've tried the fix listed [here](http://www.jargonfreehelp.com/fixing-handbrake/) and placed libdvdcss.dll in my Handbrake install, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

For now I've rolled back to 0.9.9, but if possible I'd like to get a fix for the most recent version.